# reading and displaying a text from a file line by line using javascript on html page

Tags: javascript, html

I am just learning javascript, so I need your help. I have a text file, like following;

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
.....
.....
Textn
```

I would like to read all the content from the file line by line, so text by text, and display on html page one by one. One text will blink, disappear, and then next text will blink, disappear, etc. When it comes to the end, then it will start from the beginning of the file, and continue again line by line.

How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a local text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file)

Comment: No, it does not. I did some edit on the question. Could you take a look? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="my-element">Value</h1>

  <script>
    var target = document.getElementById("my-element");

    var content = null;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", "content.txt");
    xhr.onload = () => {
      content = xhr.response.split(/\r?\n/);
      let counter = 0;
      setInterval(() => {
        target.innerHTML = content[counter++ % content.length];
        setTimeout(() => target.innerHTML = "", 500);
      }, 1000);
    };
    xhr.send();

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

But note that it doesn't work using `file` protocol and you should run a local server to use it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Sadra. However, the text does not show up. Any comment?

Comment: @yusuf Is there any error in the browser's developer console?